# How can I modify this PowerShell script to export both sections to a CSV without cutting off any data?

Tags: powershell, csv, export, ping, nslookup

I got this script from online. Figured at the very least I could figure out how to export the data to a CSV. This has proven to be so far past my ability. I've tried `Export-Csv` and pipe, but neither have had success.

I had one successful attempt but all the data got shoved into 1 column and cut off, the `-Width` parameter didn't resolve that either. The rest of the time I just get random information like `Length` or what appears to be corrupted data with number and letters jumbled up.

All this script does it run `ping` and `nslookup` on a list of IPs. I want to move it to a CSV file so I can sort the data and find IP's that are empty/not being used anymore to clean up our IP space or even identify problems in our DNS.

```
$InputFile = 'C:\Temp\list.txt'
$addresses = Get-Content $InputFile
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $InputFile
while ($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null) { $TotalIPs++ }
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Performing nslookup on each address..."    
foreach ($address in $addresses) {
    ## Progress bar
    $i++
    $percentdone = (($i / $TotalIPs) * 100)
    $percentdonerounded = "{0:N0}" -f $percentdone
    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing nslookups" -CurrentOperation "Working on IP: $address (IP $i of $TotalIPs)" -Status "$percentdonerounded% complete" -PercentComplete $percentdone
    ## End progress bar
    try {
        [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve($address) | Select HostName, AddressList
    } catch {
        Write-Host "$address was not found. $_" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Pinging each address..."
foreach($address in $addresses) {
    ## Progress bar
    $j++
    $percentdone2 = (($j / $TotalIPs) * 100)
    $percentdonerounded2 = "{0:N0}" -f $percentdone2
    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing pings" -CurrentOperation "Pinging IP: $address (IP $j of $TotalIPs)" -Status "$percentdonerounded2% complete" -PercentComplete $percentdone2
    ## End progress bar
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $address -Count 2 -Quiet) {
        Write-Host "$address responded" -ForegroundColor Green 
    } else {
        Write-Warning "$address does not respond to pings"              
    }
}
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify, simplify ...

```
Get-Content $InputFile | ForEach-Object {
    $ip = $_

    try {
        $dns = [Net.Dns]::Resolve($ip)
    } catch {
        Write-Host "$address not found.`n$_"
    }

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Address'     = $ip
        'Hostname'    = $dns.Hostname
        'AddressList' = $dns.AddressList
        'Online'      = [bool](Test-Connection $ip -Count 2 -Quiet)
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: I thank you for the reply. But I don't entirely understand what is occurring in this script. Some of it I understand, but... I guess I should play with it and see what happens.

Comment: What don't you understand about the code? It reads addresses from the input file, resolves each address to a hostname and builds a custom object with hostname, addresses and online status, and exports the objects to a CSV. The custom objects are what `Export-Csv` expects as input.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not that familiar with PS. Sorry for the delayed response. Thank you very much.